# Bing API ".Count" property not working?

Tags: c#, .net, bing, bing-api

I have been trying to bring back 20 results of images using the Bing API. Here's the code:

```
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
request.AppId = APPID;
request.Query = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(searchQuery);
request.Sources = new SourceType[] { SourceType.Image };
request.Image = new ImageRequest();
request.Image.Count = 20;
request.Image.Filters = new string[1] { "Size:Medium" };
```

Now everything on here works, including the Image.Filters property. Just not the Count property. Is there a known bug or am I just missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure really sure about this but I think you are missing setting `CountSpecified` property. Try this

```
request.Image = new ImageRequest();
request.Image.Offset = 0;
request.Image.Count = 20;
request.Image.CountSpecified = true;
request.Image.Filters = new string[1] { "Size:Medium" };
```

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't see this anywhere in the documentation. Thanks.